# Twitterizer Hometimeline exception in Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Tags: twitterizer

Trying to get user `HomeTimeLine` but I get the following exception

> 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll

My code looks like :

```
        **OAuthTokens tokens = new OAuthTokens();
        TimelineOptions properties = new TimelineOptions();

        tokens.AccessToken = "myaccessToke";
        tokens.AccessTokenSecret = "my secret accss token";
        tokens.ConsumerKey = "my consumer key";
        tokens.ConsumerSecret = "my consomer secret";
        properties.UseSSL = true;
        properties.IncludeRetweets = true;

        //Pas besoin de parser avec Twitterizer

        try
        {
            TwitterResponse<TwitterStatusCollection> timelineResponse =   TwitterTimeline.HomeTimeline(tokens, properties);
            foreach (var item in timelineResponse.ResponseObject)
            {
                String textStatus = item.Text;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Error message :"+e.Message);
        }**
```

When i try in the same code to get friends timeline it work fine exemple:

```
TwitterResponse<TwitterStatusCollection> timelineResponse =
TwitterTimeline.FriendTimeline(tokens);
```

Please i need help from everyone, thank you